# gradle pass parameter to dependsOn task

Tags: gradle

I have 3 gradle tasks: A, B, C.
B dependsOn A.
C dependsOn A.

If have an if check in A that I want to be true when B runs, false when C runs.
How do I do that?

For clarity, the real tasks are:

```
war { // task A
    webAppDirName = 'src/main/webapp'

    if (flag) {
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*.json")
        rootSpec.exclude("**/*.xml")
    }
}

ospackage { // task B
    buildRpm {
        dependsOn war
    }
}

task localTomcat { // task C
    dependsOn war
}
```

I tried setting war.flag, war.ext.flag before dependsOn, in a doFirst action, but nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a *dependsOn* chain and *mustRunAfter*.

Code:

```
task war4pkg {
    doLast {
        war.rootSpec.exclude("**/*.json")
        war.rootSpec.exclude("**/*.xml")
    }
}

war {
    webAppDirName = 'src/main/webapp'
}

ospackage {
    buildRpm {
        dependsOn war4pkg, war      # order doesn't matter
        war.mustRunAfter war4pkg    # order set here
    }
}

task localTomcat {
    dependsOn war     # nothing here.
}
```